Sum up values per unique filtered row (if GROUPBY function is not yet available)



0
A
B
C
D
E
F




1
Data List



Filter



2
date
prod.
val.

2022-12-31



3
2022-05-10
P1
15





4
2023-01-15
P1
18





5
2022-08-12
P2
30





6
2022-09-15
P3
50

Result



7
2023-06-15
P3
20

prod.
val.


8
2023-06-18
P1
80

P1
15


9
2024-05-17
P4
25

P2
225


10
2023-08-19
P5
85

P3
60


11
2022-09-30
P3
70





12
2024-04-25
P3
32





13
2025-08-29
P1
45





14
2022-03-25
P2
60





15
2022-03-26
P2
85





16
2024-05-20
P3
90





17
2024-06-03
P4
15





18
2024-07-30
P4
26






In Cell E8 I have implemented the below formula to filter the Columns A:C based on the criteria in Cell E2.
=LET(
a,FILTER(A2:C18,A2:A18<=E2),
b,CHOOSECOLS(a,2),
c,CHOOSECOLS(a,3),
d,HSTACK(b,c),
d)

All this works fine.

However, the issue is that 

the prod. are not listed unique and 
the val. is not summed up to each unique prod. 

The first issue is easy to solve with UNIQUE function but I have no clue how to solve the second issue with the sum. 
I know in the latest Excel version there is the GROUPBY function which solves this issue.  However, I do not have this function yet available in my Excel. I am using Office365 (Version 2410).
Do you know an alternative way to make it work?

Try the following formula-
=LET(
x,UNIQUE(FILTER(B3:B18,A3:A18<=E2)),
y,SUMIFS(C3:C18,A3:A18,"<="&E2,B3:B18,x),
HSTACK(x,y))

Using GROUPBY() function.
=GROUPBY(B3:B18,C3:C18,SUM,,,,A3:A18<=E2)


